# Creasing edge with "Subdivision surface" modifier on rounded surface

Tags: mesh, topology

As you can see on the images below, my problem is when I crease an edge to get sharpness with "Subdivision surface" modifier on, eventually, I get that pointed convex edge.

How can I avoid this 'bug' without complicating the topology, because obviously "mean crease" doesn't work, as well as making vertex group of the vertices on this edge and using it with the "Bevel" modifier.

Blend-file: https://yadi.sk/d/AtQSze6ogdbd4

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit better and/or post a blend file?

Comment: Try uncreasing that small edge at the middle of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use control loops for this.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> activates the tool and clicking once moves it into Slide mode. Click again or press enter to set the loop.

You can double tap <kbd>g</kbd> to slide loops after they have been added.

[image]

Removing the loops again is just as easy as adding them.  Press <kbd>x</kbd> to open the Delete menu and press <kbd>g</kbd> to delete any loops that are selected.

[image]

Deleting loops this way preserves a model's UV Coordinates, if it has any, so textures that have been baked will still be valid for the model after it has been reduced.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is not a bug, this is how it works. Creasing just "pulls" edges on subdivided surfaces towards it's original location (without subsurf) so it's natural.

Please watch this video about 3 different methods regarding the subject:

[Tips for Creating Sharp Edges While Modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBkwodrQq_4)

Edit: I may have not been clear enough why that artifact occurs. It's because you're not creasing the edge NEAR the creased one (in the middle which you want to be rounded) and so there is a "jump" between a 100% creased edge and a non-creased edge.